# Android ADT/Eclipse compatible with Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, android, eclipse, emulation, emulator

I have Windows 8.1 and have installed the android adt (sdk) with eclipse.  I can create a new app, but when I try and run it, the emulator explodes. 
The emulator window pops up than has to exit.

I get this in the console

```
[2014-02-02 23:50:33 - Emulator] This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
[2014-02-02 23:50:33 - Emulator] Please contact the application's support team for more information.
[2014-02-02 23:50:41 - lession1] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.lession1.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

I'm trying to create apps on a dell venus 8.  I can't find the windows 8.1 driver for it anywhere.

Does this kit work on windows 8.1?